# Calling transformations after `group` call in highlandjs

Tags: node.js, stream-processing, highland.js

The goal is to group items in a stream into multiple groups. Run transformations on those groups separately and then re-combine all the groups into one stream.

The only call I can use after `group` seems to be `each` and that doesn't pass individual groups to my callback it passes the entire dictionary of grouped objects. Calling `map` won't pass anything to my callback. Example:

```
const groups = stream.group(func);
groups.map(item => console.log(item)); // prints nothing
groups.each(item => console.log(item)); // instead of item being one of the groups created, it's a dictionary with all the groups included.
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

are you looking for doing this ? :

```
groups.on('error', handleError)
        .pipe(transformObject(async item => {
            some code...
```

If non, please try to give an example of what you want to do with your data.

Answer (score 0):

```js
import highland from 'highland';


const source = highland([
  { age: 21, name: 'Alice' },
  { age: 42, name: 'Bob' },
  { age: 42, name: 'Carol' }
]);


source
  .group(person => person.age)
  .flatMap(highland.values)
  // Apply transformation to each group here
  .map(group => group)
  .flatten(1)
  .doto(console.log)
  .done(() => {});
```